# Page not autofocus (couldn't do keyboard arrow scrolling on page load)

Tags: javascript, autofocus

My webpage on refresh doesn't autofocus on the webpage. So I couldn't do keyboard scrolling initially upon page load. I will need to click on the page first, then only the keyboard scrolling with arrow keys would work.

I have looked online everywhere regarding to this autofocus attribute on page content but no luck so far.

Comment: Suggestion: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Use `tabindex="-1"` in html attribute

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am using nuxt.js and I have tried adding `tabindex="-1"` in the parent but that made the keyboard scrolling stops working even after clicking on the screen, which is supposed to work.